# Processing tasks sequentially

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

i have a base class `JobBase` that has a single method `Execute()` which returns a Task. There are several classes that inherits from `JobBase` and that do some asynchronous operations. I need to put instances of the inherited classes into a list and execute them sequentially, so having job1, job2, job3, etc. job2 shall start when job 1 is finished, job 3 shall start when job2 is finished, etc.

So the queue may contain an arbitrary number of jobs.
For example: job1 downloads some content, job2 reads the content. In an another scenario, job1 downloads some content, job2 downloads some other content, job3 reads the content, etc.

**Example**

```
// The base class
public abstract class JobBase
{
    public abstract Task Execute();
}

// inherited jobs
public class Job1 : JobBase
{
    public override Task Execute()
    {
        // this one: return Task.Run()
        // or this one?: 
        Task task = new Task(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        });
        return task; 
    }
}

public class Job2 : JobBase
{
    public override Task Execute()
    {
        Task task = new Task(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        });
        return task; 
    }
}
```

The main program:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var jobs = new List<JobBase>();
    jobs.Add(new Job1());
    jobs.Add(new Job2());

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Count; i++)
    {
        var jobNr = i;
        Task task = jobs[jobNr].Execute();
        tasks.Add(task);

        task.Start();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Starting WaitAll");
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Actually, the tasks are executed and i have no control aboute the order they are executed (or finished). Additionally, I would like to get a result (bool) of each job and continue with the next job, if the previous one was successful.

I read and tried the SequentialTaskScheduler, solutions with TaskCompletionSource, the tutorial about [Processing tasks as they complete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/).
I cannot work with ContinueWith since the number of jobs(tasks) is not known.

Please have a look at the following example and its output. For simplicity reasons there is one class `Job` that inherits from `JobBase` which takes an index and a delay value:

```
public class Job : JobBase
{
    private readonly int _index;
    private readonly int _delay;

    public Job(int index, int delay)
    {
        _index = index;
        _delay = delay;
    }

    public override Task Execute()
    {
        Task task = new Task(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job {0} before delay", _index);
            await Task.Delay(_delay);
            Console.WriteLine("Job {0} after delay", _index);
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

Adding some instances to the task list, such as

```
jobs.Add(new Job(1, 3000));
jobs.Add(new Job(2, 2000));
jobs.Add(new Job(3, 1000));
```

I get the following result:

```
Starting WaitAll
Job 2 before delay
Job 3 before delay
Job 1 before delay
Finished
Job 3 after delay
Job 2 after delay
Job 1 after delay
```

(Job3 finishes at first, since the delay is less than job2, etc.)

The desired result is:

```
Starting WaitAll
Job 1 before delay
Job 1 after delay
Job 2 before delay
Job 2 after delay
Job 3 before delay
Job 3 after delay
Finished
```

What is the best approach to run the async tasks sequentially? I am free to change the signature of the Execute method, e.g returning Task or whatever.

Comment: Do realize that if you take a look at the desired result the total running time will be around 5s (3+2+1). When running in parallel it will take around 3s.

Answer (score 1):

> So the queue...

What queue? Your current code uses a `List<T>` with `Task.WaitAll`, which is fine if you know how many tasks you're waiting for. It doesn't work as a "task runner", because it's not possible to interrupt the `WaitAll` and say "oh, you have a new task now".

It sounds to me like what you're looking for is [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var jobs = new ActionBlock<JobBase>(x => x.Execute());
  jobs.Add(new Job1());
  jobs.Add(new Job2());
  jobs.Complete();

  Console.WriteLine("Starting Wait");
  Task.WaitAll(jobs.Completion.Wait()); // only using Wait because this code is in Main

  Console.WriteLine("Finished");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

`ActionBlock<T>` by default will execute one task at a time.

> Additionally, I would like to get a result (bool) of each job and continue with the next job, if the previous one was successful.

If you report errors with exceptions, then the `ActionBlock` will stop processing on the first failed job.

Comment: You are right, it was a queue before, in this example its a list. I didn't know about the Dataflow library, so ActionBlock is what i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async void Main(string[] args)
{
    var jobs = new List<JobBase>();
    jobs.Add(new Job(1, 3000));
    jobs.Add(new Job(2, 2000));
    jobs.Add(new Job(3, 1000));

    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Count; i++)
    {
        var t = jobs[i].Execute();
        await t;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Note that we are no longer using

```
 Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

since that allows the Tasks to run in parallel. We just await them in the loop.

Modify the Job class to this:

```
public class Job : JobBase
{
    private readonly int _index;
    private readonly int _delay;

    public Job(int index, int delay)
    {
        _index = index;
        _delay = delay;
    }

    public override Task Execute()
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job {0} before delay", _index);
            await Task.Delay(_delay);
            Console.WriteLine("Job {0} after delay", _index);
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

Note the change of

```
Task task = new Task(async () =>
```

to

```
Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
```