# Run Multiple HttpResponseMessage Task in a sequence

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, httpresponsemessage

In a console application I've created a List of Task in which im adding three async tasks:

```
static  void Main(string[] args)
        {
List<Task> task_list= new List<Task>();


Task task_1=new Task(async () => await Task_method1());
Task task_2=new Task(async () => await Task_method2());
Task task_3=new Task(async () => await Task_method3());

task_list.Add(task_1);
task_list.Add(task_2);
task_list.Add(task_3);

 Task.WaitAll(task_list.ToArray());
            foreach (Task t in task_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} Status: {1}", t.Id, t.Status);
            }
Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And here's the method definition of 3 Task:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Task_Method1()
{
    //Code for Response

     return Response;
} 
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Task_Method2()
{
    //Code for Response

     return Response;
} 
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Task_Method3()
{
    //Code for Response

     return Response;
}
```

Problem is that they are running parallely, and there's no serialized order of tasks. I searched a lot but get didn't get an appropriate solution for running them in series.
For reference see the image below:

**RUN1:**
[image]

**RUN2:**
[image]

**RUN3:**
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603997/processing-tasks-sequentially/39614002#39614002

Comment: You want to have a look at the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318860/async-method-not-running-in-parallel) SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have omitted some code, as even if the tasks complete in arbitrary order, your `List`'s order should remain unchanged, yet you show your output with the `List`'s order changing.

Then re actually doing it, perhaps I'm missing something, but if you want them to run in order why not just do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}

private async Task MainAsync()
{
    var response1 = await Task_method1();
    var response2 = await Task_method2();
    var response3 = await Task_method3();

    // Write results, etc.

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```